# mdadm raid0 with disks of different size?

Tags: linux, lvm, software-raid

Currently I'm using LVM just to merge a few disks of different size.  I want to know if it is possible to use `mdadm` with stripes instead of LVM?

Will it give me additional performance?  Will it use all the space across disks of different size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

However, there is no big difference in raid0 and lvm stripe; seems lvm is better choice.

raid0 with mdadm supports drives with different size and its size equals to sum capacity of drives.

Unfortunately raid0 mdadm can't add new drives without rebuilding the whole raid, however lvm does.

Comment: ok, can you provide some info about how to create this kind of lvm (with stripes) any links

Comment: also found some benchmarks which shows that mdadm faster than lvm (i think i this array will never changed during it's lifetime)

Comment: The size is the number of drives times the *smallest* drive.  Raid can't use partial space from the larger drive; it has to have equal amounts from each.

Comment: ok, is lvm with stripes can be used on drives with different size ?, or it have same limitations as md ?

Comment: i made little research and found what mdadm stripes can use disks with different size, currently i have following
major minor  #blocks  name
   8        5  488636416 sda5
   8       16  488386584 sdb
   9      127  977020928 md127
md127 maid from sda5 and sdb, sum off sizes is 977023000, so i lost 2072, but if calculate sum of smallest (488386584) devices i should lost 249832 instead

Comment: I can verify you can have slices of unequal size on LVM. When the smallest PV runs out, it's no longer used in striping (of course). The remaining PVs are used, until they run out too. If you have just ONE larger PV, you'll end up with some chunk of data only one that PV, so there'll be a performance hit. However, this is fantastic for organically grown setups where performance isn't a huge issue. I've never had to try unequal slices with MD RAID, but I suspect what @psusi said is correct, and MD stripes across `ndisks * min(disk_size)`, not `sum(disk_size)`.

Comment: looks like md bevavior same as lvm, currently i made array from 200+160+80 gb, as result have sum of this disks http://pastebin.com/1eFxTGmp , and also as i raid wiki sayin about ability to extend raid without rebuilding